Can anyone give me the source and authenticity of the following hadith?
The woman who commits adultery while her husband is providing for her is cursed in this world and the Hereafter.
I couldn't find the source and authenticity in any website. If someone has knowledge please reply.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. It would be beneficial if you had the original Arabic wording/text quoted in your post.

@Med1Saif No I found this in some websites. So am looking for authenticity. Any similar text will also do the purpose

Perhaps linking the websites which reference this hadith might help provide relevant context?
